# Android - Extending Another Class with Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I trying to use Universal Image Loader, inside a fragment but I am getting Null Pointer Exception. The original flow looks like this:

```
Activity A extends AbsListViewBaseActivity
{
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//this flow is working, images are showing
imageLoader.displayImage(values2.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE_NAME2 ).toString(), holder.image, options2);
}
}

AbsListViewBaseActivity extends BaseActivity
{
     public ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}
```

Using Fragments, I wanted to copy the implementation above but I am getting null pointer in imageLoader. The only thing that I can't do is extend the AbsListViewBaseActivity with also extends the BaseActivity(the one who initialize the imageloader) because below extends the `Fragment`

```
public class CollectionDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity {
static ImageAdapter imageAptr ;
 public BaseActivity base;

 public static class DemoObjectFragment extends Fragment {
((GridView) absList.listView).setAdapter(imageAptr);
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//Getting Errors in here/ null pointer 
base.imageLoader.displayImage("Image Path", holder.image, options2);
}

}
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at com.jinisys.restoplusordering.CollectionDemoActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(CollectionDemoActivity.java:403)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1447)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-18 18:49:36.073: E/AndroidRuntime(20970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe the `CollectionDemoActivity` should be extending `AbsListViewBaseActivity` and not `FragmentActivity`. If that's not applicable, you should include the older project as an external project/library in order to use directly the `public class ImageAdapter`.

Comment: Imageloader need to be configured and buit before using it !!

Comment: @g00dy , can you guide me in creating a library out of my older project, basically there are only 2 involve classes the AbsListViewBaseActivity and the BaseActivity and also the Universal-Image-Loader.jar. So given this how can I create an new library in eclipse? your help will appreciated.

Comment: Hi, for the library project creation, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject. You can make the project "Ultimate Image Loader" as a library project and then re-use it in the new application, see this: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Imageloader` needs to be configured in the `BaseAdapter` class, so what I did since the above codes are quite confusing. I directly use this on my main Activity: `BaseActivity.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getBaseContext()));` instead on relying the configuring in `AbsListViewBaseActivity` class.